# Getting distorted WAV files after using scipy.io.wavfile.write, librosa.output.write_wav

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, scipy, wav

The first one returns a WAV file with alien like sound(the original sounds more like simple techno beat)

The second returns a WAV file only when set with np.float32, also with distortion.

rate, signal = wavfile.read('audio/0b0bd019.wav')

wavfile.write(filename = 'clean/0af9f0b4.wav', rate =rate , data=signal)

librosa.output.write_wav(path = 'clean/0af9f0b4.wav',y=signal.astype(np.float32), sr=rate)

Expecting to return the same WAV sound as the original.

Comment: What is the data type of the original file? Can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using: https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.0/
I am not sure why your formulation didn't work but this package worked for me.